# What is the keyboard shortcut to switch between the 4 workspace

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I'm relearning Linux and I totally forgot how to do this. Please help.

Comment: I mean between the 4 workspaces.

Comment: Please click the edit button, rather than commenting to change details.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch workspace with following shortcut:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd>